# Javascript time track

Tags: javascript, cookies

my requirement is 15 minutes after visiting the site, user will navigate to registration page. And I need to track the page even after open that page again, user will navigate to registration page.

As the requirement I think it will be possible with cookie, but I need to count the time of visiting the site. When site visiting minutes reach to 15 js will fire a function and there I can set the cookie and redirect.

Can any one please help me to track the site visiting minutes by js?

Comment: i would hate a site that does that

Comment: I did not find  out the time tracking solution, settitmeout need to stay the page but I need to count the total time

Comment: I would set a timer in java script and fire an event after 15 mins, and make ajax call to redirect the page.

Comment: @Mandar: That wouldn't work unless the client stayed on the same page for 15 mins, which is very unlikely to happen

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem : I agree, missed that. good point !

Comment: This is just bad user experience. The most you could get away with is some sort of slide out alert, and I personally find that annoying and tacky. If your content is worth registering for, than people will sign up when/if it is necessary. Just make it easy for them to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with epoch, it *can* be done using `localStorage`:

```
(function (timer)
{
    var now = new Date();
    var redirect = function()
    {
        location.href = 'register url';
    }
    if (!localStorage.getItem('registrationMinutes'))
    {
        localStorage.setItem('registrationMinutes',(+now)+60000*15);//time +15 minutes
    }
    if (localStorage.registrationMinutes <= +now)
    {//on page load, check if 15 mins are up
        return redirect();
    }
    timer = setTimeout(redirect,localStorage.registrationMinutes - now);//call function when time is up
})();
```

Just include this little function on all pages. You might want to set a cookie like `userIsRegistered`, and *not* set the timeout when the client has already been registered.
Just know that this code will be sent to the client, and he or she is still free to disable cookies, JS,... and, I think, `localStorage` isn't supported by older IE browsers (there's a surprise!)
If all this is a bit much, here's a simple copy-paste snippet:

```
(function (url,now,timer)
{
    var redirect = function()
    {
        location.href = url;
    }
    if (!localStorage.getItem('registrationMinutes'))
    {
        localStorage.setItem('registrationMinutes',(+now)+60000*15);//time +15 minutes
    }
    if (localStorage.registrationMinutes <= +now)
    {//on page load, check if 15 mins are up
        return redirect();
    }
    timer = setTimeout(redirect,localStorage.registrationMinutes - now);//call function when time is up
})('redirectUrl',new Date());
```

just replace the `'redirectUrl'` string with your url, and it should work just fine. There is also no need to change variable names: it's all contained in this anonymous function's scope, so there is no conflict with variables declared in the parent scope.